# Using the "in" operator in Python 3.10 Match Case

Tags: python, python-3.10

Is there a "in" operator in python 3.10 Match Case like with if else statements

`if "\n" in message:`

the in operator doesn't work in match case

```
match message:
    case "\n" in message:
```

This doesn't work.
How to have something like the "in" operator in Match-Case.

Comment: It looks like an if statement is more suitable for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness, it can be done indirectly using [guards](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#guards) (as used in the other answer).

```
match message:
    case message if "\n" in message:
        ... some code...
    case message if "foo" in message:
        ... some other code...
```

Note using the name `message` in each case statement is not required (this does have the side effect of binding the name `x` to a value):

```
match message:
    case x if "\n" in x:
        ... some code...
    case x if "foo" in x:
        ... some other code...
```

Or you can also use wildcards (which skips the name binding):

```
match message:
    case _ if "\n" in message:
        ... some code...
    case _ if "foo" in message:
        ... some other code...
```

But you're probably better off just using an if statement since using match-case is more code and has worse readability for this situation

```
if "\n" in message:
    ... some code ...
elif "foo" in message:
    ... some code ...
else:
    ... some code ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In `match-case` we can use the `split()` method on the message string.

Example:

```
def match_case_with_if(command):
    match command.split():
        case [*command_list] if 'install' in command_list:
            print(f"Hey you are installing {command_list[-1]}....")
        case [*command_list] if 'uninstall' in command_list:
            print(f"Are you sure you want to uninstall {command_list[-1]} ?")


match_case_with_if('pip install numpy')
# Output: Hey you are installing numpy....
match_case_with_if('pip uninstall numpy')
# Output: Are you sure you want to uninstall numpy ?
```

Here, the string can be split into a list and if condition can be applied on its contents.
*Hope this helps!!*

Comment: Thanks for your great solution i think match case just isn't useful for this and ended up settling with a if else statement. Still thanks for your solution.